# Character Encoding Issue using WordPress + Zurb

Tags: html, character-encoding

I am not sure what is wrong in this but the french version of site is giving trouble in rendering the right characters. This is strange when I check source code is perfect but in HTML page view it is giving some strange characters.

Here is the page URL and very first text you can find with strange character. If you look into the source wrapped with `<p>` which is giving correct text `Bénéficiant`.

http://dev2.apolloblake.com/fr/voix/

I am using WordPress + Zurb with blank theme, so no idea what is wrong here.. would you please help me..

Comment: Actually looks good to me.

Comment: Ah! than what's wrong with my and some other people browser??? can you please guide me..

Comment: Try use sublime text 2 as a code editor and copy the code into there and see if there are any funny characters in it. Sometimes if I copy content from skype or photoshop or word I get wierd characters

Comment: I am using Sublime Text 2 and 3 and document has UTF-8 so I think the issue is something else in my browser since other people also able to see right characters.